# JMeter performance plugin having XXE vulnerability. Any other alternatives?

Tags: security, jenkins, jmeter

JMeter performance plugin is listed with vulnerability: https://plugins.jenkins.io/performance/
So currently its not safe to use this plugin(https://www.jenkins.io/security/advisory/2021-11-12/#SECURITY-2394).

Anyone have other alternatives for JMeter test reporting using Jenkins? Or do we have any other solution to fix this vulnerability and still use this performance plugin?
[Screenshot of Performance Plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98zy9.png)

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is [open source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/performance-plugin) so you're welcome to contribute the fix via [pull request](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull)

If you're a BlazeMeter customer you can request the fix via [BlazeMeter Support](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket)

Answer (score 0):

The fix is already in repo, but the new version is not built and deployed to Jenkins. This cannot be done by open source community.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/performance-plugin/pull/205/commits/8f94845417cfa0089f5b1fea3a5b8d09d7f333d0